# Picking a Total from the Current Month

Tags: google-sheets

I have this working formula (below)

```
=SUM(QUERY(QUERY({{A2:B},{ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), WEEKNUM(A2:A, 16), ))}}, 
 "select *", 0), 
 "select Col2 
  where Col3 matches '"&WEEKNUM(TODAY(), 16)&"'", 0))
```

What do i need to change to get my Total from the current month?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet and example of desired output

Comment: This post will give you an idea, I can only post comments (and that doesn't help); https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124658/picking-the-total-from-the-next-week

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED, used another type of formula

Comment: Hi woodie, please elaborate a little on what your actual solution was, otherwise the answer won't really be useful to anyone with the same problem.  Thanks!